# Cakephp customer redirect in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I am migrating from an old content mgt to cakephp. Articles in the old site were linked like this:

```
url/what-you-need-to-know-about-your-vehicles-axle-shafts-a655.html
```

The new links are like this:

```
url/articles/what-you-need-to-know-about-your-vehicles-axle-shafts-a655.html
```

I do not what user to experience any 404 when clicking on old links.

How do i forward the user to the new link every time they click on the old?

I attempted some of the [techniques outlined here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this near the top of your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^articles/
RewriteRule ^(.+\.html)$ /articles/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: For SEO purposes R=301 (Moved Permanently) would be better. R's default is 302 (Found)

Comment: Brilliant! Jon that did it. Thanks a million

Comment: one small addition. It was forcing other non related pages to redirect so my made a small edit

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^articles/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).html$ /articles/$1 [L,R]